# How to get the form input values using HttpServletRequest?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Well, it may be a noob question, but I can't where I am doing wrong after long hours trying to debug it. I am trying to submit the form using ajax, then in my controller, I will parse the input values using HttpServletRequest. However, all the values are null in the server side. I have make sure the names are matching, but ...

This is my form:

```
<spring:url var="createBundle" value="/createbundle" htmlEscape="true"/>
 <form id="c-b-form" method="post" action="${createBundle}">
    <div class="modal-form">
        <table class="table-form">
            <tr class="t-details">
                <td class="c-70">
                    <label for="c-b-t">Title</label>
                    <div class="input-txt">
                        <input id="c-b-t" class="txt" type="text" name="bname"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="c-30">
                    <label for="c-b-a">Amount</label>
                    <div class="input-txt">
                        <input id="c-b-a" class="txt" type="text" name="bamount"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <label for="c-b-c">Category</label>
                    <select id="c-b-c" name="cid">
                        <option value="0">Category</option>
                        <option value="1">Applicace</option>
                        <option value="2">App Game</option>
                    </select><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">        
                <div>
                    <input id="c-b-btn" class="submit-btn acc-btn" name="c-b" type="submit" value="Save" />
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>

 $('#c-b-btn').click(function(event) {
    var btnId    = '#' + $(this).attr('name');
    var formId   = btnId + "-form";
    var nameId   = btnId + '-t';
    var amountId = btnId + '-a';

    var nameVal   = $(nameId).val();
    var amountVal = $(amountId).val();

    var isNameValid = false;
    var isAmountValid = false;

    if(nameVal.length <= 0) {
        isNameValid = false;
    } else {
        isNameValid = true;
    }


    if(!parseFloat(amountVal) || !$.isNumeric(amountVal)) {
        isAmountValid = false;
    } else {
        isAmountValid = true;
    }

    if(isNameValid && isAmountValid) {
        alert("name\t" + nameVal 
                + "\namountVal\t" + amountVal);
        var json = {
                "bname" : nameVal, 
                "bamount" : amountVal,
                };
        $.ajax({
            url: $(formId).attr('action'),
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            },
            success : function(response) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("erorr");
            }
        });
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

In my controller I am trying to do parse the input value:

```
System.out.println((String)request.getParameter("bname"));
//System.out.println((String)request.getParameter("cid"));
```

I print out null values; however, the alert displays the correct values that I wanna get in my controller.

Comment: Try sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `JSON`

Comment: I tried it, but it is still null. Well If I don't use ajax, then it works fine

Comment: I didnt change to data: json. It works now. Thank you. I have look many tutorials and most of them have showed me the above code. Wonder if there is any specified differences that I need to be awake of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're sending JSON when you server side script is expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`(this is what an html form will post<sup>1</sup>), this is the default type $.ajax sends so there is no need to set a content-type and the will even be encoded for you once you pass an object as the data parameter.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: $(formId).attr('action'),
        data: json,
        type: "POST",
        success : function(response) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("erorr");
        }
    });
```

1. or `multi-part/formdata` for a file upload

Answer (score 0):

As Musa suggested, you can use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (which the form default) and just post the form directly without using the click function to convert the data into json format.  or you can try this Ajax code without JQuery, it works for me all the time, just modify the code with your form fields,

```
     var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
     var password  = document.getElementById("password").value;
     var doc = 
     {                                                
          "username" : username, 
          "email" : username,                                    
          "password" : password,                      
     };                                                              
     var url = httpsserver+"/login";
     postJason(url, doc, loginCallback);

  //
function getRequest()
{
  //***** create the AJAX object to do HTTP requests *******
  var request = (typeof window.ActiveXObject != 'undefined')
    ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();

  if (request == null)
   alert("Error creating request object!");
  return request;
}  

//
//
function postJason(url, doc, callback)
{
  var request = getRequest();
  var value = JSON.stringify(doc);

  request.open("post", url, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = callback;
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  request.send(value);
}
```